# change date to dd-mm-yyyy using php $_POST

Tags: php, datetime

I have an online date form. When people select the date on the website it reads dd-mm-yyyy however when i receive the email it reads yyyy-mm-dd.

What code do I need to use to change the date to mm-dd-yyyy

HTML CODE:

```
<form id="easy" name="contact" method="post" action="submit.php" onSubmit="return checkform()">

    <div class="input">
        <label for="date">Enter your birthday:</label>
        <input type="date" id="date" name="date">
    </div>

    <button type='submit' class="button" id='send_message'>Send</button>
</form>
```

PHP Code to send me the email (submit.php):

```
 <?php

error_reporting(0);
$emailAddress = 'MYEMAILS@EMAIL.COM';

require "form/class.phpmailer.php";
$msg='You have been contacted by '.$_POST['name'].'<br /><br />

<table style="padding:0;margin: 0;padding: 3px;width: 100%;border: 1px     solid #000000;border-collapse: collapse;border-spacing: 0;">
<tr> 
<td style="width:35%;background:#1775ca;color:#FFF;padding:3px;">Field</td>
<td style="width:65%;background:#1775ca;color:#FFF;padding:3px;">Entry</td>
</tr>


<tr>
<td>Date</td><td>'.$_POST['date'].'</td>
</tr>


</table>
<br />
You can contact '.$_POST['name'].' via the email '.$_POST['email'].' <br />
The recorded IP is '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].''; 
?>
```

Comment: did you try date_format($_POST['date'], 'm/d/Y');
?

Comment: more information
http://php.net/manual/ru/datetime.format.php

Comment: Yep, i tried 
    <tr>
<td>Date</td><td>'.date_format($_POST['date'], 'm/d/Y').'</td>
</tr>

and then the form was blank with no date in it.....

Comment: @Melzy  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the date() and strtotime() functions to create a string of just about any format.

Change this:

```
<td>Date</td><td>'.$_POST['date'].'</td>
```

To:

```
<td>Date</td><td>' . date('m-d-Y', strtotime($_POST['date'])) . '</td>
```

Comment: strtotime has a number of flaws which are overcome by using the (newer) datetime class

Comment: @smith  I agree with you that the datetime class is robust and I use it for certain things, however strtotime will handle this readily.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
 $your_date = "2018-03-24";
 list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $your_date);
 $new_date = sprintf("%s-%s-%s", $day, $month, $year);
 echo $new_date;
 //Output: 24-03-2018
```

Comment: its a date not a string, and should not be manipulated this way.

Comment: Even if the variable contains a date format in PHP can be used as string and the answer is valid if he decide  to use it

Comment: This in a example based in my experience, I won't let any references from an author. I that case he can check the PHP manual for more information.

Answer (score 0):

the format the user sees is based on their location, but the value returned to you will always be "yyyy-mm-dd".

you can convert that using the datetime class:

```
$myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $_POST['date']);
$newDateString = $myDateTime->format('m-d-Y');
```

REf: [The DateTime class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and  [input type="date"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date)